# How do I create a dynamic list of enum flags and then pass into another method

Tags: c#, enums

I have a scenario like the following, I have an enum, I get some text which is parsed to create a list of enums which I want to pass into ReportResults which will create an email based on the flags passed in.  I don't have access to change the enum or the ReportResults method, is there a way to pass in something like the resultFlags variable? Is there a way to use an Enum.TryParse to create a single item to pass in?  (there must be times where serialization requires something like this)

```
    [Flags]
    public enum Result
    {
        None = 0,
        Warning = 2,
        Error = 4,
        Success = 8,
        Failure = 16
    }

    public void ProcessResultValues(string log)
    {
        var resultFlags = new List<Result>();

        /// Process log text, add Result flags to the resultFlags list

        ReportResults(resultFlags);
    }

    public void ReportResults(Result results)
    {
        /// Based on the flags, generate a text to describe if the process succeeded or failed and if there were any warnings or errors encountered during processing.
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the \[Flags\] Enum Attribute mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c)

Comment: A bit odd to have a flag that could be both `results & Result.Success` and `results & Result.Failure`.

Comment: Well, it's just an example, but you could have something where a process completes successfully even if it had warnings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since `Result` is set up correctly as a *bit flags enum* (which means the one enum variable can hold several enum values), you can just `or` them together to get a single combined *enum* to pass around. The easiest way to do that would be using the [Enumerable. Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.8) method

> Applies an accumulator function over a sequence.

```
var result = resultFlags.Aggregate((x, y) => x |= y);
```

It's the same as combining them manually, eg

```
Days meetingDays = Days.Tuesday | Days.Thursday;
```

The reason why *bit flags* work, is the way the numbers are laid out, each value is not mutually exclusive and can be packed and unpacked in binary easily using *bitwise operations* (hence the name *bit flags*). They have been around for ever.

---

**Further Reading**

[Enumeration types as bit flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/enumeration-types#enumeration-types-as-bit-flags)

> You can use an enumeration type to define bit flags, which enables an
>   instance of the enumeration type to store any combination of the
>   values that are defined in the enumerator list
>
> You create a bit flags enum by applying the System.FlagsAttribute
>   attribute and defining the values appropriately so that AND, OR, NOT
>   and XOR bitwise operations can be performed on them. In a bit flags
>   enum, include a named constant with a value of zero that means "no
>   flags are set."

Answer (score 1):

You can try this but the `None` value should be 1 because if 0 the flag will be always on.

```
[Flags]
public enum Result
{
  None = 1,
  Warning = 2,
  Error = 4,
  Success = 8,
  Failure = 16
}

public void ProcessResultValues(string log)
{
  var resultFlags = new List<Result>();

  // For test
  resultFlags.Add(Result.Warning);
  resultFlags.Add(Result.Success);

  Result results = default(Result);
  resultFlags.ForEach(value => results |= value);

  ReportResults(results);
}

public void ReportResults(Result results)
{
  // For test
  foreach ( Enum value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Result)) )
    if ( results.HasFlag(value) )
      Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

*Output*

```
Warning
Success
```

*If None is 0:*

```
None
Warning
Success
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Olivier, I actually used your code, but it seems it's essentially the same as The General's so I selected his as the answer since it was submitted a few minutes earlier.